# REPL hangs on SublimeREPL for Clojure (Windows PC)

Tags: clojure, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I'm trying to use SublimeREPL with Sublime Text 2 so that I can programme with Clojure.  I have installed SublimeREPL using the package manager.

I go to

> Tools > SublimeREPL > Clojure

and start a repl this seems to start fine, but whatever I type in and hit enter does nothing.  It does not return anything not even an error.

I have [Lein](http://leiningen.org/) installed.

I am using a **Windows PC**

Has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have had this trouble with versions 2 and 3. From what I can see, it's a known issue. I have also reported it on GitHub: https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/356

Also, this solution worked for me: [Sublime Text, SublimeREPL, Clojure & Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245763/sublime-text-sublimerepl-clojure-windows-8)